# Easiest way to recast variables in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

New to databasing, so please let me know if I'm going about this entirely wrong.

I want to use databases to store large datasets (I use R to analyze data, which cannot load datasets larger than available RAM) and and I'm using [SQLite-Manager](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/) in FireFox to import .csv  files. 99% of the time I use reals, but would like to avoid all the clicking to manually cast each of 100 columns as `REAL` (the default in SQLite-Manager is `TEXT`).

Is there a way I can I can quickly/easily cast all columns as `REAL`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you make a script to be interpreted by the SQLite shell?

Run `sqlite my_db < script.txt` with contents of `scripts.txt` following:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
 col1 REAL,
 col2 REAL,
 [...] generate those lines with a decent text editor
);

.separator ;
.import 'my/csv/file.csv' foo
.q
```

Note that dot-commands of the SQLite shell are available using “.help”. Imports are rudimentary and won't work if you have double quotes (remove them). Only the , is interpreted as a separator, you cannot escape it. If needed you can use a multicharacter separator.

Also be sure that file.csv is UTF8-encoded.

Comment: Now I'm glad I switched from textmate to Vim a few months ago... to be complete, I can create the 100 entries easily in Vim... `:.!printf 'Ret(\%s) REAL\n' {1..100}`

Comment: Otherwise you could use the [visincr.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=670) plugin (yy99p, then CTRL-V, and block highlight the column of numbers, and `:I`